# add remove class transition scrollheight

Tags: jquery, css-transitions

I noticed that with CSS transitions is possible to restart the animation at any point,

now I want to create a button that toggles the height of its parent animating it between

- its "closed" height (e.g. 50px)
- and its normal (full expanded) height

---

```
$('.panel-trigger').each(function() {

    var $parent = $(this).parent();

    if (!$parent.hasClass('closed')) {
        $parent.css('height', $parent[0].scrollHeight);
    }else{
        $parent.css('height', '50px');
    }

    $(this).on('click', function() {

        if ($parent.hasClass('closed')) {

            $parent.css('height', $parent[0].scrollHeight);
            $parent.removeClass('closed');

        } else {
            $parent.addClass('closed');
            $parent.css('height', '50px');
        }
    });

});
```

[image: jsFiddle]

The code is actually working on my osx chrome 46.0.2490.80,

but I am not sure if it is the good way to achieve that result.

I would like to know if there is a more simple and efficent way to do it

Any help is really appreciated

Comment: the `height` css requires a `"px"` after the number, or another identifier like `em` or `%`

Comment: Yes, as @SterlingArcher said you need **specific value assigned to `height`.**

Comment: No you don't, jQuery will add a `px` value automatically. It's actually the other way around, you don't need to use them in the other `.css()` either. Seems opinion based for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
        $parent.css('height', $parent[0].scrollHeight );
```